# Is it possible to use Regex through Hexadecimal to find email addresses

Tags: python, regex, computer-forensics

Not sure if this is even possible but I have been looking at using Regex to get an email address that is in Hex. Basically this is to build up some of my automated forensic tools but I am having problems on making a suitable Regex algorithm.

Regex for email: /^([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})$/

Hex values:

```
@ = 40
. = 2E
.com = 636f6d
_ = 5f
A/a = 41/61 [1]
Z/z = 5a/7a
- = 2d
```

This is what I have got at the moment (it only takes into account lower case and .com). But it doesn't work! Have I messed something simple up?

```
"/^([61-7a]+)40([61-7a]+)23(636f6d)$/"
```

[1] I know email can only be lower case but I need to take uppercase into account too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### define classes

```
@ = 40
. = 2E
com = 636f6d
_ = 5f
a-z = (4[1-9a-f]|5[0-9a])
A-Z = (6[1-9a-f]|7[0-9a])
- = 2d
```

### substitute into your regex

```
/^([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})$/

/^(((4[1-9a-f]|5[0-9a])|(6[1-9a-f]|7[0-9a])|[0-9]|5f|2E|2d)+)40(([0-9]|(4[1-9a-f]|5[0-9a])|(6[1-9a-f]|7[0-9a])|2E|2d)+)2E(((4[1-9a-f]|5[0-9a])|(6[1-9a-f]|7[0-9a])){2,6})$/
```

### breaks down to...

```
/^
(
    (
        (4[1-9a-f]|5[0-9a])     // a-z
        |(6[1-9a-f]|7[0-9a])    // A-Z
        |[0-9]                  // 0-9
        |5f                     // _
        |2E                     // .
        |2d                     // -
    )+ // 1 or more times
) 
40
(
    (
        [0-9]                   // 0-9
        |(4[1-9a-f]|5[0-9a])    // a-z
        |(6[1-9a-f]|7[0-9a])    // A-Z
        |2E                     // .
        |2d                     // -
    )+ // 1 or more times
)
2E                              // .
(
    (
        (4[1-9a-f]|5[0-9a])     // a-z
        |(6[1-9a-f]|7[0-9a])    // A-Z
    ){2,6} // between 2 and 6 times
)$/
```

Comment: First off apologies for the wrong hex values! . is 2E :/ But thanks for the algorithm it still is missing something but it looks close!

Comment: I think also the classes for `a-z` and `A-Z` need upper/lower case alternatives ... `(4[1-9a-fA-F]|5[0-9aA])`

Comment: For some reason the 4[1-9a-f] doesn't work at all. I can't seem to get python to parse the 4? I have also tried an online took and it doesn't understand the 4. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: I am sure the error is something else - there is nothing wrong with the `4`. The class should include upper case too `4[1-9a-fA-F]`. Post a link to the online tool with your test data, and regex.

Comment: Final algorithm thanks to you Billy is r"( ( (4[0-9a-fA-F]|5[0-9a-fA-F])|(6[0-9a-fA-F]|7[1-9a-fA-F])|[0-9]|[(5f|5F)]|[(2e|2E)]|[(2d|2D)]+)[40](4[0-9a-fA-F]|5[0-9a-fA-F])|(6[0-9a-fA-F]|7[1-9a-fA-F])|[0-9]|[(5f|5F)]|[(2e|2E)]|[(2d|2D)]+[2e|2E]((((4[0-9a-fA-F]|5[0-9a-fA-F])|(6[0-9a-fA-F]|7[1-9a-fA-F])){2,6}) ))" Thanks

Comment: I am glad you posted the final regex, I wanted to see it finished!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are approaching the problem wrong. Assuming that you are using the standard hex-char equivalencies, you should convert the email out of hex first, then use the email regex. This can be done by simply processing the email two chars at a time, and using `chr(int('piece, 16))` on each piece.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `base64.b16decode(str)` is probably preferable these days.

Comment: I intend to use this process to run through whole computer systems, hence why I wanted to just run regex over the file. Raw images are the same size as the hard drive itself, so if I have a 1tb hard drive I will need 2tb just to change everything into ASCII values.

Comment: I could be wrong, but from what I know, regexing a filesystem is a bad idea as well. You are going to have to load 1TB of data into your RAM anyways.

Comment: I intend to utilise the principles behind data carving to avoid any RAM problems. They already scan through huge file systems looking for headers and footers of files. I don't care about the time it takes to run through the program but I do care about the storage I use. So if I need to split the raw data up I will do that.

Comment: That would definitely work. You'd just have to make sure you have enough overlap to avoid chopping emails of a reasonable length.

Comment: E.g., if you expect to have emails of up to 50 real characters, you would need 100 hex characters of overlap at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to look at the documentation for regular expressions in Python (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

For example, [61-7a] will match any of 6, 1-7 or a.

Comment: `6` is included in `1-7` - maybe you mean `6[1-7a]` which would match a `6` followed by `1-7` or `a`

Comment: What I meant was that you can have only one digit or a sign on each side of the '-' otherwise they will be considered as one of the options. You are correct that 6 is included in 1-7 but if you had something like a1-7b then it would be split into a, 1-7, b.

Comment: I see, you are differentiating what could look like a range of hexi-decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly away from what you're looking to achieve but take a look at [Bulk Extractor](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Bulk_extractor) which parses through a drive and carves out email addresses and lists them in popularity order.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment anywhere since this questions is already answered, I guess, but I think this needs to be said.

The approach you are taking is actually worse than converting each individual character into ASCII equivalent.  You are actually converting each byte into **2 ASCII characters**.

Just to reference a part of the REGEX pattern that you posted as a final/working pattern: `4[0-9a-fA-F]`
You are attempting to find chars `@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO`.  You have `a-f` **and** `A-F` because you are trying to account for the Hex code being stored in upper case or lower case.  Hex code on a hard drive does not get stored in upper or lower case (it doesn't even get stored in hex codes).  You are accounting for whatever tool is presenting this data to you - in ASCII.

What tool are you using to access this data?

If you are using python to read a dd image file, then you need to use a regex that goes after the raw data.  That would be something like `[\x40-\x4f]` to replicate the above.  This is all unnecessary though because `[@-O]` would accomplish the same thing.

I am not sure exactly how you are testing this, but I suspect that you are pasting hex codes into an online REGEX testing engine.  That testing engine is then interpretting those hex codes as 2 individual characters, not as a pair of nibbles from a byte.